# Filtering Rows from Multi-Header DataFrame by values from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I'm building a Python script to do the following:

1. List CSVs in directory
2. Read single CSV file to DataFrame -> "data" (rows 2 (Parameter Name) and 3 (Parameter Unit) are defined as header).
3. Only keep rows if value in columns "TMOD1", "TMOD2", "TMOD3" and "TMOD4" are 0 (if one is not 0, the entire row has to go)
4. Drop all columns (-> parameters) with the unit "bit"
5. Drop all rows with more than e.g. 10 "NaN" values
6. Append filtered DataFrame "data" to DataFrame "result"
7. Iterate steps 2-7 for all CSV files
8. Save resulting DataFrame "result" as new CSV file

I'm stuck at how to implement steps 3 and 4, everything else works fine.

I've tried the following for step 3:

```
data = data[(data.TMOD1 == 0) & (data.TMOD2 == 0) & (data.TMOD3 == 0) & (data.TMOD4 == 0)]
```

And the following for step 4:

```
data.drop(labels='bit', axis=1, level=1, inplace=True)
```

Step 4 works perfectly when leaving out Step 3 and using a multi header row DataFrame.

However, Step 3 only works when switching to a single header row DataFrame - in which case Step 4 obviously won't work.

I guess I messed up with calling the correct header level.

Comment: What is `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: Quite a lot - but maybe this extract helps:

print(data.columns)

MultiIndex(levels=[['TMOD1', 'TMOD2', (...) '],  [(...) 'SEC', 'unitless', 'bit', (...)]], labels=[[43, 73, (...) ]]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data[(data['TMOD1']['bit'] == 0) & (data['TMOD2']['bit'] == 0) & (data['TMOD3']['bit'] == 0) & (data['TMOD4']['bit'] == 0)]
```

Seems to work. No idea why it didn't when I tried it yesterday.

Is there any possibility to leave the second label ('bit') blank? The labels sometime differ (e.g. 'bit', 'bits' or 'unitless') in the raw data.